# filter data between Sql service analysis filter web-part and Excel-Web access Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have given connection between Sql service analysis filter web-part and Excel-Web access web-part when I try to filter it I am not getting filtration in  Excel-Web access web-part and showing error as below.Can any one help me how can I solve this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

enable the powerpivot service or set it up.

**cause**

> Excel Services returns this error when you query PowerPivot data in an
>   Excel workbook that is published to SharePoint, and the SharePoint
>   environment does not have a PowerPivot for SharePoint server, or the
>   SQL Server Analysis Services (PowerPivot) service is stopped.
>
> The error occurs when you slice or filter PowerPivot data when the
>   query engine is not available.

**solution**

> For PowerPivot workbooks that were created in a SQL Server 2008 R2
>   version of PowerPivot for Excel, you must install the SQL Server 2008
>   R2 version of the Analysis Services OLE DB provider. This error will
>   occur if you installed the provider, but did not register the
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ChannelTransport.dll file. For more
>   information about file registration  [Install the Analysis Services OLE DB Provider on SharePoint Servers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210608%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487858(v=sql.110).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487858%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

**EDIT**

> The second scenario is when you have a server in a SharePoint farm
>   that runs Excel Services, but not PowerPivot for SharePoint. In this
>   case, the application server that runs Excel Services must be manually
>   updated to use both the newer version of the provider, as well as
>   install an instance of the Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.dll file in
>   the global assembly. These components are necessary for connecting to
>   a PowerPivot for SharePoint instance. If Excel Services is using an
>   older version of the provider, the connection request will fail.

just follow the directions in the link:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210608%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

scroll down to:

**Install the SQL Server 2008 R2 OLE DB Provider to host earlier version workbooks**

or

**Install the SQL Server 2012 OLE DB Provider on an Excel Services server**

Comment: Ali it seems the given url of tech-net is very therotical.Can you provide me any blog-post .Hope you reply me

Comment: just updated answer

Answer (score 0):

This might work with SQL 2008 I don't know. 
But SQL Server 2012 OLE DB Provider simply does NOT install Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ChannelTransport.dll (into GAC_MSIL, Program files, or anywhere else) so there's no file to set in registry.